# Nauty graph isomorphism weighted edges

Tags: graph-isomorphism

I want to use sofeware Nauty version 2.5 to check if **edge-weighted** graphs are isomorphic to each other. However weighted edge is not supported by Nauty.

Professor McKay mentioned that there's an example in the manual showing how to make an equivalent unweighted graph. Can any one tell me which example is the one?
:-P

The manual I have is "nauty and Traces User’s Guide (Version 2.5)".

Many thanks!!